# How to upload multiple image for a mobile website?

Tags: php, image, mobile, upload

I have a php website for mobile where user can upload multiple images.But when i open it on mobile browser and trying to select multiple images but it select only one file.

How i select multiple file on mobile like facebook.
I use

```
<form method="post" id="saveProfileForm" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input type="file"  id="takePictureFied" multiple="multiple">
</form>
```

But it not work for mobile
Plz help me

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this

```
<form action="file-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Send these files:<br />
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Send files" />
</form>
```

as mentioned at http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: I think nipa just wants one upload field and select multiple files (multiple="multiple") instead of multiple fields. But I think this only works for desktop browsers

Comment: Right @BartScheffer any idea for mobile site ... How facbook does?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [link](http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/inputs_mobile.html) you can't. Mobile browsers don't support this feature

Comment: check `http://share.pho.to/` , this website provide multiple photo upload for mobiles too .